# Could not load ultrafast preset

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

Code:

```
import ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg');
import ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ffmpeg(tempFilePath)
        .videoCodec('libx264')
        .audioCodec('copy')
        .preset('ultrafast')
        .output(outputFilePath)
        .on('end', resolve)
        .on('error', reject)
        .run();
    });
```

Getting error:

```
/presets/ultrafast could not be loaded: Cannot find module
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used this package myself, but from the looks of it, there is no `ultrafast` module in the source code here: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/tree/master/lib/presets

You may need to pass the option via the following:

```js
import ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg');
import ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ffmpeg(tempFilePath)
        .videoCodec('libx264')
        .audioCodec('copy')
        .output(outputFilePath)
        .addOption([  "-preset" , "ultrafast"  ])
        .on('end', resolve)
        .on('error', reject)
        .run();
    });
```